# When to change my address on W2

Tags: united-states, state-income-tax, form-w-4, form-w-2

I am employed (W2) by a company based out of AZ and I live in CO. I am purchasing a house in OR as my primary and moving there. I will acquire the house in 30 days, however I won't move in for 90 days (FYI: Bank requires I move in 60 days from closing). During that time, the house is being rented on VRBO and I will do a lot of traveling and working out of hotels or other VRBO places in OR, AZ and MT. At what point do I change my address with the company I work with?

I have already validated we have other remote W2 employees in OR. So, this shouldn't be an issue for my employer. I'm just not sure what the timing should be. Do I do this when I close on the house in OR? Or when I physically relocate there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note you change it on the W-4.

The key thing is to change it  when you have changed the primary place you are living.

When you start the process of getting mail changed, cars registered, and registering to vote you should also change the W-4.

Because there will be a lag between when you submit it to your company and when it takes effect don't worry about trying to time it perfectly. What you do have to note is the date your primary residence changed, so you know what date to put on the part-year tax forms for the state.